# What is the strut 2 equivalent of strut 1 logic:iterate tag property attribute

Tags: struts2, struts

In strut 1 we use logic:iterate tag to iterate over the list. While defining this tag we use property attribute and strut 1 call getter method of this attribute to get Iterable Object. What is the equivalent in strut 2 for same thing ?

As show in below code in strut 1 we are using logic:iterate tag to iterate over iterable object. And Strut 1 get this itearble object by calling getter method of property attribute(records in this example) which is defined by name attribute(DataForm in this example).

i.e. in below example, strut 1 internally calls getRecords() method which is present in DataForm class to get the iterable object.

How can we achive same thing in strut 2 ?

```
<div STYLE=" height: 300px; width: 860;font-size:12px; overflow: auto;">              
<html:form action="/discardHorisBulk.do" target="content">
      <table width="840">      
      **<logic:iterate id="horisList" name="DataForm" property="records" indexId="indexId" type="com.waghtech.client.isTech.model.Horis" >**
        <tr>
          <%
              String bgColor="#fffafa";
              int size = indexId.intValue();
              if (indexId.intValue() %2 == 0)
              {
                bgColor="#dcdcdc";
              }

              java.util.HashMap params = new java.util.HashMap();       

              params.put("key",  horisList.getKey() );
              params.put("clientName", horisList.getClientName() );
              pageContext.setAttribute("paramsName", params); 
          %>

           <td bgcolor=<%=bgColor%> width="200">
           <html:link page="/mapClient.do" name="paramsName" scope="page" >            
                <bean:write name="horisList" property="clientName"/>
           </html:link> 
           </td>
           <td bgcolor=<%=bgColor%> width="60">
               <bean:write name="horisList" property="startDate"/>
           </td>               

           <td bgcolor=<%=bgColor%> width="60">
               <bean:write name="horisList" property="endDate"/>
           </td>               
        <!-- 
            <td bgcolor=<%=bgColor%> width="200">
               <bean:write name="horisList" property="displayFd"/>
           </td>
            -->
           <td bgcolor=<%=bgColor%>  width="200">
               <bean:write name="horisList" property="userfileName"/>
           </td>               
           <td bgcolor=<%=bgColor%>  width="40">               
               <html:multibox name="dataForm" property="markedRecords" value="<%=horisList.getClientName()%>">    
                <bean:write name="horisList" property="key"/>  
               </html:multibox>
           </td>               
        </tr>   
    </logic:iterate>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When you iterate the current object is pushed onto the top of the value stack, so its properties are accessible via plain OGNL. This is discussed in the docs and in many tutorials/examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use value attribute for it. something like this :

```
 <ol>
<s:iterator value="records">
  <li><s:property value="userfileName"/></li>
</s:iterator>
</ol>
```

This will call the getter method of this list and within those when you use value attribute it will call getter for those fields in records class.